# Intel RAPL default power limits are too low

Tags: linux, cpu, power-management, intel, cpu-frequency

I am running Arch Linux with kernel `5.17.4-arch1-1` on Asus Zenbook 14 UX435EG Laptop. 
Specs: 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel Core i7 1165G7 (4 cores, 8 threads, TDP-down: 12W @ 1.20 Ghz, TDP-up: 28W @ 2.80 Ghz, Max Turbo frequency: 4.70 Ghz) 
Memory: 16 GB LPDDR4X 
Disk: 512GB Intel NVME M.2 SSD 
GPU: Iris Xe, NVIDIA Geforce MX450

So, when running a processor-intensive task, like `stress -c 8`, the processor jumps to 80 C and 3.5-ish Ghz but quickly gets throttled down after less than a second to 900 Mhz at 55 C (the same temperature when idle). This happens with all governors and all power hints. After some digging around, I realized that the issue is with intel RAPL drivers. Disabling the drivers or setting high limits causes the frequency to stay at 3.5 GHz but also overheat the CPU to 95 C which causes a force power off after about 5 mins. 
The limits for `intel-rapl:0` are as follows:

```
./constraint_0_max_power_uw:28000000
./constraint_0_name:long_term
./constraint_0_power_limit_uw:64000000
./constraint_0_time_window_us:27983872
./constraint_1_max_power_uw:0
./constraint_1_name:short_term
./constraint_1_power_limit_uw:64000000
./constraint_1_time_window_us:2440
./constraint_2_max_power_uw:0
./constraint_2_name:peak_power
./constraint_2_power_limit_uw:121000000
./constraint_2_time_window_us:0
```

`intel-rapl-mmio:0`:

```
./constraint_0_max_power_uw:28000000
./constraint_0_name:long_term
./constraint_0_power_limit_uw:10000000
./constraint_0_time_window_us:27983872
./constraint_1_max_power_uw:0
./constraint_1_name:short_term
./constraint_1_power_limit_uw:25000000
./constraint_1_time_window_us:2440
```

`intel-rapl:0` limits seem to be ok, but the mmio ones are way too low. I tried setting all of the limits to 28 Watts (the TDP-up) but the frequency also didn't go above the TDP-up base frequency which was 2.80 GHz. 
The problem also exists on the LTS kernel, mainline 5.18 RC3 kernel, and 5.16.

Where are these default values got from? What are the optimal values for my CPU model so I can set them during boot?

Comment: Do you have power limits set in your BIOS? I would examine your settings, and remove any that you find there.

Comment: @Bram No, also, after a lot of investigating, I figured out that there is an ACPI table missing in my firmware, which should describe the temperature trigger points. On Windows, the closed source driver handles it, but on Linux, there is practically no way to get proper throttling